# Failed: No provider for Config! (Icon -> Config) in Ionic2 unit tests with karma and jasmin

Tags: ionic2, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm writing unit tests for an ionic2 app but I get following error when the template contains some ionic elements
e.g.

```
<ion-icon > </ion-icon>
```

Failed: No provider for Config! (Icon -> Config)

Any idea?

Comment: Tried adding beforeEachProviders(() => [Config]);  to the spec.ts file but no luck  (import {Config} from 'ionic-angular')

Comment: add provider to @component { provider: [your-provider] }

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how the previous solution works, because `Config` needs `App`, which needs `Platform`, which needs `Keyboard` which needs... maybe it is because you do not configure testing module asynchronously, which you should ;) simply try this:

```
import { IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { YourTestedComponent } from './pathto.component.ts'

beforeEach(async(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [ IonicModule.forRoot(this) ], // this loads ionic deps
    declarations: [ YourTestedComponent ],
  });
}));
```

This should fix it
Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

you're not allowed to use template in @app, try to use templateUrl: 'build/app.html' and create a app.html with your tags in it.

Comment: this does not answer the question, it's about a missing provider

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem. This worked for me:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from "@angular/core/testing";
import { Config, IonicModule } from "ionic-angular";

beforeEach(() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    declarations: [
    ],
    imports: [
      IonicModule,
    ],
    providers: [
      Config,
    ],
  });

  fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
  component = fixture.componentInstance;
});
```